# Magento2 Reorder using REST Api

Tags: magento2, sales-order, quote, rest-api, reorder

Can anyone let me know if we can Reorder in Magento2 using REST webapi? Actually i have made one api and used same code as magento default reorder does, here is my code in API function using order_id as parameter:

```
public function reOrder($orderId)
    {
        $order = $this->orderApiRepository->get($orderId);
        $cart = $this->cart;
        $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            try {
                $cart->addOrderItem($item);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($e->getMessage()), $e);
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue is when i am checking response in postman, it returns null instead cart data, please let me know if anyone has done same type of things. please check below screenshot of POSTMAN api:

[image: POSTMAN API]

Comment: Got any solution ?

Comment: have you got solution for this

Comment: Nope didn't get any solution on it

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?

Comment: @bhargavshastri Have you got any solution for reorder rest API ?

Comment: @bhargavshastri Please share your solution I am facing same issue while creating reorder API ?

Answer (score 2):

Use below code for Reorder api

Create YourNameSpace/Module/etc/webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V1/reorder/:orderId" method="POST">
    <service class="YourNameSpace\Module\Api\ReorderInterface" method="createReorder"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self" />
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="cartId" force="true">%cart_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

Create YourNameSpace/Module/Api/ReorderInterface.php

```
    <?php

namespace YourNameSpace\Module\Api;

interface ReorderInterface
{
    /**
     * 
     *
     * @api
     * @param int $cartId
     * @param int $orderId
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function createReorder($cartId,$orderId);

}
```

Create YourNameSpace\Module\Model\Reorder.php

```
<?php

namespace YourNameSpace\Module\Sales\Model;

use YourNameSpace\Module\Api\ReorderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface;

class Reorder implements ReorderInterface
{
    protected $quoteRepository;

    protected $orderRepository;

    protected $quote;

    protected $productRepository;

    protected $cartItemInterface;

    protected $cartItemRepository;

    public function __construct(
        CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        OrderRepository $orderRepository,
        Quote $quote,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        CartItemInterface $cartItemInterface,
        CartItemRepositoryInterface $cartItemRepository
    )
    {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->cartItemInterface = $cartItemInterface;
        $this->cartItemRepository = $cartItemRepository;
    }


    /**
     * @param $cartId
     * @param $orderId
     * @return bool
     */
    public function createReorder($cartId,$orderId)
    {
       // $quoteRepo = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);

        $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($items as $item) {

            try {
              $this->addOrderItem($item, $cartId);
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                return false;

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function addOrderItem($orderItem,$quoteId)
    {
        /* @var $orderItem \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
        if ($orderItem->getParentItem() === null) {
            //$storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            try {
                /**
                 * We need to reload product in this place, because products
                 * with the same id may have different sets of order attributes.
                 */
                $product = $this->productRepository->getById($orderItem->getProductId());

            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                return $this;
            }

            $this->cartItemInterface->setQuoteId($quoteId);
            $this->cartItemInterface->setSku($product->getSku());
            $this->cartItemInterface->setQty($orderItem->getQtyOrdered());

            $this->cartItemRepository->save($this->cartItemInterface);

        }
    }

}
```

Pass order id in your api with customer authentication , so it will add your order items in customer cart and gives you true in return so later on you can get cart items by calling /V1/carts/mine/items api.

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: If the product have any option, then this will not working. It shows error like 'You need to choose options for your item.'. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

After Declaration of Web api the Reorder logic in model file ReOrder.php

```
<?php
namespace HIT\Customer\Model;
use HIT\Customer\Api\ReorderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface;

class ReOrder implements ReorderInterface
{

    protected $orderRepository;

    protected $productRepository;

    protected $cartItemRepository;

    protected $cartManagementInterface;

    protected $customerRepositoryInterface;

   public function __construct(

        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
         CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface,
        OrderRepository $orderRepository,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $cartManagementInterface,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface


    ){

        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
        $this->cartRepositoryInterface = $cartRepositoryInterface;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
         $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
         $this->cartManagementInterface = $cartManagementInterface;
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    public function reOrder() {

        $data = array();

        $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $post = json_decode($json);

        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($post->order_id);

        $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($items as $item) {

            try {
              $this->addOrderItem($item, $post->customer_id);
               $data['status'] = "true";
               $data['msg'] = "Product addedd to your cart Successfully";

            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                   $data['status'] = "false";
                    $data['msg'] = $e->getMessage();

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $data['status'] = "false";
                    $data['msg'] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

         echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
         exit();
    }
    public function addOrderItem($item,$cid)
    {
        if ($item->getParentItem() === null) {
                  $cartId= $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote')->loadByCustomer($cid)->getId();

                  if(empty($cartId)){
                    $cartId = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart(); 
                    $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cartId); // load empty cart quote
                    $quote->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
                    $customer= $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($cid);
                    $quote->setCurrency();
                    $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
                    }else{
                         $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cartId); 
                    }

                    $_product = $this->productRepository->getById($item->getProductId());    
                    $quote->addProduct($_product,$item->getQtyOrdered()); 
            try {

                 $quote->collectTotals()->save();


            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
                exit();
            }


        }
    }





}
```